# What's the third arg in fcntl()

Tags: c++, c

I'm not sure about the third arg in `fcntl()`, I do know that it's different when the second arg changes, and it is a pointer when the second arg is `F_GETLK` etc. But when the 2nd arg is `F_GETFL` etc, what should 3rd arg be?

From APUE, it is 0 when 2nd arg is `F_GETFL`

Thanks anyway:)

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html

Comment: What part of the documentation didn't you understand?

Comment: @miqdadamirali Oh.I get it.Thanks a lot

Comment: @EJP I've got it.Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fcntl() can take an optional third argument.  Whether or not this
>          argument is required is determined by cmd.  The required argument
>          type is indicated in parentheses after each cmd name (in most cases,
>          the required type is int, and we identify the argument using the name
>          arg), or void is specified if the argument is not required.
>
> F_SETLK, F_SETLKW, and F_GETLK are used to acquire, release, and test
>          for the existence of record locks (also known as byte-range, file-
>          segment, or file-region locks).  The third argument, lock, is a
>          pointer to a structure that has at least the following fields (in
>          unspecified order).
>
> As with traditional advisory locks, the third argument to fcntl(),
>          lock, is a pointer to an flock structure.  By contrast with
>          traditional record locks, the l_pid field of that structure must be
>          set to zero when using the commands described below.

This link will assist you with your question
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html